# Create a custom ranking website

Tags: web, development-environment

I want to create a website that does all this,

1)Pull livestats of sport's player,
 tally it with user's prediction.
rank sport's player based on the 
outcome of user's prediction,
and also rank users based on their
prediction's outcome.

im a newbie to coding and web development,how can i get this done?

Comment: This question appears to be too broad.

Comment: There is no definite answer to your question. Since your a newbie to coding and web development, first invest some time in learning and practicing the tools and technologies required and then move on with this project.

Comment: Hi,what would be the required technology and tools be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select your technologies to be used and your server(s) to be used, then watch videos, read tutorials about the server(s), technologies used and when you feel you are ready, write some code. By the way, if you are a newbie to algorithmic thinking as well, then try to learn a few things about algorithms, complexity, data structures as well.

Comment: hi,what technology would best suit my project?

Comment: The one you choose, this question is about preference, my answer would only reveal my personal taste instead of an objectively best answer, as the word "best" means something else for everyone. Define "best" and then I can give you an answer. This site discourages broad questions and answers and we should be comfortable with that by reducing subjectivity to zero.